# Why do I need a QTranslator for localized button texts in a QMessageBox on Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qtranslator

I'm developing a Qt application that runs on Linux and Windows. I'm on a German locale.

When building it on Linux, I get the correct translations for the standard buttons displayed by e. g. a `QMessageBox::question` with `QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Cancel` buttons set ("Ja", "Nein" and "Abbrechen" in my case).

If I build the code on Windows however, I only get the C locale (English) texts for those buttons ("Yes", "No" and "Cancel").

After some searching, I found a globally working solution by adding

```
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QLibraryInfo>
```

and

```
QTranslator qtTranslator;
if (qtTranslator.load(QLocale::system(), QString::fromUtf8("qt"), QString::fromUtf8("_"),
                      QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath))) {
    app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
}
```

to my `main.cpp`.

Using this, I also get the translated strings on Windows. On Linux however, the `qtTranslator.load` call fails and thus, nothing happens to the state I had before, so I ended up putting that code inside an `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` block.

This works, but seems a bit hacky to me. Plus, I don't understand why I get the translated strings on Linux by default and not on Windows.

Is the way I do it the correct solution? And if so, why do I need that additional code on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code on this and tested.

```
static QTranslator qtTr;
qtTr.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(), QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
installTranslator(&qtTr);
```

Comment: I don't think this will change anything. On my linux machine, `QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)` gives me `/usr/share/qt5/translations`, which does not even exist. So it will fail again on Linux. Well, and on Windows, it works as I posted it above … I still wonder why I need this code on Windows and not on Linux!

Comment: @TobiasLeupold what version of qt you use?

Comment: First 5.6.2, then 5.7.1. Same behavior for both versions.

Comment: @TobiasLeupold what about compilator? msvc, mingw?

Comment: cmake + gcc on Linux, cmake + mingw and qmake + mingw on Windows.